# Is a*∅ infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, regular-expressions

I've started to learn regular expressions in one of my classes

I know that a* is infinite, which leads me to believe that a*∅ is not infinite, since concatenating any language by a empty set is just empty set, similar to multiplying by zero. Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.  Any set concatenated with the empty set gives the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's correct.  An element of $a^*\emptyset$ would be a concatenation of an element of $a^*$ with an element of $\emptyset$.  But there aren't any elements of $\emptyset$!  So there is no way to build an element of $a^*\emptyset$, and it is empty.